# codeigniter form to submit selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I need to make a form that have a dropdown to select record and when click on the submit button can edit.
Everything is working fine just the button not get the selected id.

Here is a screenshot of my form:

[image]

## View:

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/edit_instrumento; ?>" method="post" id="instrumentos_form">
  <div class="col-lg-12 well">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="formSep">
            <p><span class="label label-default">Selecione Usuário</span></p>
            <div class="">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <select class="uni_style" name="nome" id="user_drop">
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <?php foreach($users as $member){ ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $member->user_id; ?>"><?php echo $member->nome; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="formSep">
                <p><span class="label label-default">Selecione o Tag</span></p>
            <div class="">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <select class="uni_style" name="tag" id="tag_drop" >
                  <option value="">Selecione</option>
                  <?php 
                  $sl_class=$row['instrumento_id'];
                  ?>
                  <?php foreach($instrumentos as $instrumento){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $instrumento['instrumento_id']; ?>"><?php echo "Tag: { ". $instrumento['tag']." }     &#8594;Instrumento: { ". $instrumento['instrumento_nome']." }"; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="hrmag"/>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Editar" /></p>
      </div><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

## Controller:

```php
public function instrumento($instrumento_id){
    $posts = $this->input->post();
    $lista = $this->instrumento_model->get_instrumento($instrumento_id);
    $html="";
    foreach ($lista as $k => $v) {
        $html.= '<option value="'.$v['instrumento_id'].'">'.$v['instrumento_nome'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $html;
}
function edit_instrumento($instrumento_id){
  $data['success']=0;
  if($_POST){
    $data_post = array(
        'user_id'          => $_POST['nome'],
        'instrumento_nome'      => $_POST['instrumento_nome']
    );
    $this->instrumento_model->update_instrumento($instrumento_id,$data_post);
    $data['success']=1;
    $this->load->view('admin/edit_instrumento',$data);
    redirect(base_url().'admin/h');
  }
  $data['instrumento']=$this->instrumento_model->get_instrumento($instrumento_id);
  $this->load->view('admin/edit_instrumento',$data);
}
```

## Model:

```php
function get_instrumentos(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('instrumentos');
    $this->db->join("users", "users.user_id = instrumentos.user_id",'inner');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();  
}
function get_instrumento($instrumento_id){
    $this->db->select()->from('instrumentos')->where(array('instrumento_id'=>$instrumento_id));
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->first_row('array');
}
function update_instrumento($instrumento_id,$data){
    $this->db->where('instrumento_id',$instrumento_id);
    $this->db->update('instrumentos',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking wrong post value

In view its `tag`,

```
<select class="uni_style" name="tag" id="tag_drop" >
```

in controller its `instrumento_nome`

```
'instrumento_nome'      => $_POST['instrumento_nome']
```

This is wrong, use same name in both the places.

**Solution**

Either change name in view,

```
name="instrumento_nome" and in controller use as $_POST['instrumento_nome']

or 

name="tag" and in controller use as $_POST['tag']
```

Comment: Hi, yes i just was tryng but it is not working anyway, could you consider that it is instrumento_nome becaue it is not working even this.

the problem is that the Editar bottom can't get the instrumento_id that i selected.

Comment: have you changes in both the places?? in view as well as controller??

Comment: yes, the dropdown get his data already with JS so no problem with this.
what i need is, after selected from dropdown and press the bottom "editar"  i can edit other form.

Comment: always i user a table the using foreach and can add a bottom to edit.
but in this case i do different... want a dropdown that when i select the option and press no the botton can go to the other form to edit it.

Comment: is the second dropdown coming from ajax??

Comment: i need o change the table to dropdow link this: 
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ymdXi.png

Comment: yes!

<pre><code>
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  //jQuery("#form_instrumentos").hide();
  dropdownElement = $("#user_drop");
  dropdownElement.find('option[value=3]').remove();

  jQuery("#user_drop").change(function(){
            var selecionado = $(this).val();
   
            jQuery.get("<?php echo base_url().'instrumentos/filter_instrumento/'; ?>"+selecionado,
            function(retorno5){
                jQuery("#tag_drop").html(retorno5);
            });
        });
 });
</script>
</code></pre>

Comment: is both select present inside the same form??

Comment: Yes it is! 
the scenario like this:
1) select the user and the tag that they in same table called "instrumentos" and after select edit it.  "the selection workes good by JS"
2) when i click on the botton go to "admin/edit_instrumento/instrumento_id" that there the form to can edit.

got it ?

the problem is the bottom not go to the id selected from the dropdown, so i need to know where is the problem!!!

Comment: but ur not sending `/instrumento_id` in form action.

Comment: not working too! it is give the last row inside the DB and not respect the selective one!

Comment: I sent you a request on twitter could you please check it :)